# MySQL query syntax error when used in PHP

Tags: php, iphone, mysql

**iPhone code**

When I use this code it always show error password but I am entering correct credentials.

```
    NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UserName=%@&UserPas   sword=%@",userNameTextField.text, userPasswordTextFiled.text];

    NSString *hostStr = @"http://www.celeritas-solutions.com/emrapp/connect.php";
     = [hostStr stringByAppendingString:post];
    NSData *dataURL =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [ NSURL URLWithString: hostStr ]];    
    NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    if([serverOutput isEqualToString:@"Yes"]){
           UIAlertView *alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Congrats" message:@"You are authorized "
                                                          delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
       [alertsuccess show];
           [alertsuccess release];


    } else {
            UIAlertView *alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Username or Password Incorrect"
                                                          delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alertsuccess show];
            [alertsuccess release];

    }
```

I am getting validate username and password from data base but it gives sql syntax error that

```
   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your   MySQLserver version for the right syntax to use near 'AND UserPassword=' at line 1

  mysql_select_db("emriphone", $con);


  $u=$_GET['UserName'];
  $pw=$_GET['UserPassword'];

   $check ="SELECT UserName,UserPassword from appUsers WHERE UserName=$u AND UserPassword=$pw";

  $login=mysql_query($check,$con) or die(mysql_error());

  if(mysql_num_rows($login)==1){

  $row =mysql_fetch_assoc($login);
  echo 'YES'; exit;
   }

 else{
   echo'NO';exit;
  }

 mysql_connect($con);
```

Comment: why you have tagged this question for **iPhone** ?

Comment: because i am conneting this data base with iphone app and validating password and username

Comment: so what? There is not any code related to iPhone!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quotes for variables in the query `''`

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I have done like this but every time my script sends No  in echo

Comment: give  if(mysql_num_rows($login)>0)

Comment: just echo and see ur query ,run it in query browser , check it

Comment: if(mysql_num_rows($check)>0)
  }

Comment: SELECT UserName,UserPassword from appUsers WHERE UserName='' AND UserPassword=''NO this is the output when i run this in browser without sending any input

Comment: seeing through ur query..... i cannot see any variable values passed to username and password..... so it will obviously go to NO statement...check for ur $u and $pw variable... send some variables through it and run it in ur sql browser

Comment: listen i am passing values from iphone app to this script you can see above iphone code

Comment: no there is no problem with if condition i have checked but there is issue with post when i direct give user and password with out get in php script it workis fine

Comment: echo your $u and $pw and see whether u can get the values of it

Comment: may i echo this in this script becuase i am posting values from iphone app

Comment: yes i have given echo and runing that script directly is prints nothing in

Comment: i have been checking in iphone code but not getting i have spent more than 5 hours on it

Comment: post a new question for not able to fetch the username!! some one will help u out...

Comment: soul now i have got the values of username and password in echo

Comment: echo ur query and see... check if its working properly or not

Comment: sorry i just NSLog post which i was sending it has values but in querry echo same result as earlier

Comment: i use jquery and json to fetch the values and later pass through json to controllr

Answer (score 3):

You need to place single quotes in your query -

```
$check ="SELECT UserName, UserPassword 
         FROM   appUsers 
         WHERE UserName='$u'           
         AND UserPassword='$pw'";      // These are probably varchar data columns 
                                       // in your db. In that case, you should 
                                       // put single quotes like this.
```

When you search text fields in your database, you should place single quotes around them. Otherwise MySQL will report it as an error.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to add single quotes around around the username and password parameters in your where clause since I'm assuming those are strings. In MySQL you need to wrap the strings in single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming username and password are text fields you should correct as following

```
$check ="SELECT UserName,UserPassword from appUsers WHERE UserName=$u AND UserPassword=$pw";
```

To

```
$check ="SELECT UserName,UserPassword from appUsers WHERE UserName='$u' AND UserPassword='$pw'";
```

included single quote around username and password

Answer (score 1):

```
 $check ="SELECT UserName,UserPassword from appUsers WHERE UserName=$u AND UserPassword=$pw";
```

And because you're using mysql, be sure to sanitize the Username and password against SQL Injection by using the following:

```
$u = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['UserName']);
$pw = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['UserPassword']);
```

And final thought; Use POST instead of GET for a login page ;D hehe

Answer (score 0):

Protect yourself from sql injection while you're at it

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT UserName,UserPassword from appUsers WHERE UserName='%s' AND UserPassword='%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($u),mysql_real_escape_string($pw));
```